# Is there any way to provide authentication for riak database?

Tags: riak

I want to **authenticate riak node** with a username and a password like we normally do authentication for SQL databases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Riak has no built-in authentication or authorization mechanism, as it was designed to be used in private networks and to be simple to configure. If you are using the REST API, we recommend inserting a reverse-proxy between Riak and the client that can handle the authentication. Members of the community have used nginx and Apache for this purpose.

In the future this may change (it is something on our long term roadmap) but probably not at least until a year from now.

**Update 1/29/2014:** Riak 2.0, currently in tech preview and slated for release end of Q1/2014 has authentication and user access controls.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to do reverse-proxy implementation between riak and nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [authentication modules](http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/cookbooks/Authentication/) or [pre-commit hooks](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/commit-hooks/)

Commit hooks is simple for username:password authentication.